# Disabled Trigger still working

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g

We are using an Oracle 10 DB which uses several triggers to retrieve values from sequences which are used as primary keys. One of these triggers is **disabled** but it seems that it is still firing because the records in the table are inserted successfully with a valid primary key.

How is that possible? Why is this "before insert" trigger still working although it is disabled?

Comment: 1- are you sure it's disabled ? did you query `select status from user_triggers where trigger_name = 'THE_TRIGGER_NAME'` ? 2- are you sure there are no other triggers that might be doing it ? can you try `alter table TABLE_NAME disable all triggers` ? 3- how are you inserting the records ? as a simple `insert statement` ?

Comment: Chances are your insert statement probably calls the sequence directly. Otherwise it'll be what A.B.Cade said.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! It's simple: Like Jeffrey Kemp notes the query calls the sequence directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the trigger calls the sequence to get a PK value only if the insert statement does not provide one (PK is null). The application that does the insert probably calls the sequence and provides a value for the PK.

Maybe you can test it yourself by inserting a record into the table with PK value is null. If you get an error the trigger is disabled.